# Attempting to add softsub to H264 vcodec in AVI container

Tags: video, ffmpeg

Having the following video
MediaInfo

```
General
Complete name                            : r.avi
Format                                   : AVI
Format/Info                              : Audio Video Interleave
File size                                : 8.51 MiB
Duration                                 : 1 min 0 s
Overall bit rate                         : 1 189 kb/s
Movie name                               : Ralph Breaks the Internet 4K
Writing application                      : Lavf57.71.100

Video
ID                                       : 0
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : High@L4.2
Format settings                          : CABAC / 4 Ref Frames
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, ReFrames                : 4 frames
Codec ID                                 : H264
Duration                                 : 59 s 977 ms
Bit rate                                 : 1 010 kb/s
Width                                    : 1 920 pixels
Height                                   : 1 080 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Variable
Frame rate                               : 23.976 (24000/1001) FPS
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.020
Stream size                              : 7.22 MiB (85%)
Title                                    : @NAHOM
Writing library                          : x264 core 148 r2795 aaa9aa8
Encoding settings                        : cabac=1 / ref=4 / deblock=1:0:0 / analyse=0x3:0x113 / me=hex / subme=8 / psy=1 / psy_rd=1.00:0.00 / mixed_ref=1 / me_range=16 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=2 / 8x8dct=1 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_pskip=1 / chroma_qp_offset=-2 / threads=12 / lookahead_threads=2 / sliced_threads=0 / nr=0 / decimate=1 / interlaced=0 / bluray_compat=0 / constrained_intra=0 / bframes=3 / b_pyramid=2 / b_adapt=1 / b_bias=0 / direct=3 / weightb=1 / open_gop=0 / weightp=2 / keyint=250 / keyint_min=23 / scenecut=40 / intra_refresh=0 / rc_lookahead=50 / rc=crf / mbtree=1 / crf=23.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpmin=0 / qpmax=69 / qpstep=4 / ip_ratio=1.40 / aq=1:1.00

Audio
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AAC LC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec Low Complexity
Codec ID                                 : FF-2
Duration                                 : 1 min 0 s
Bit rate                                 : 160 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel layout                           : L R
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 kHz
Frame rate                               : 46.875 FPS (1024 SPF)
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 1.18 MiB (14%)
Alignment                                : Split accross interleaves
Interleave, duration                     : 21  ms (0.51 video frame)
Interleave, preload duration             : 750  ms
```

I'm trying to add softsub using ffmpeg command

```
ffmpeg -y -i test1/r.avi -c:v libx264 -map v:0 -map a:0 -map 1 r.avi
```

But I get the following error:

```
[avi @ 0x55d2e8c30d20] Subtitle streams other than DivX XSUB is not implemented. Update your FFmpeg version to the newest one from Git. If the problem still occurs, it means that your file has a feature which has not been implemented.
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Not yet implemented in FFmpeg, patches welcome
Error initializing output stream 0:0 --                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
[libmp3lame @ 0x55d2e8c394c0] 4 frames left in the queue on closing
```

Any Idea what am I doing wrong

Comment: "Update your FFmpeg version to the newest one from Git." Did you do this? If so and independent of that: "Subtitle streams other than DivX XSUB is not implemented....If the problem still occurs, it means that your file has a feature which has not been implemented." Is your stream divx xsub? If not it seems to indicate you are doing something that is not supported.

Comment: Newest version from the git master branch will give you the same message. Why do you want AVI? Can you not use a modern format such as MKV?

Answer (score 1):

The same error (Subtitle streams other than DivX XSUB is not implemented ...) is also found when trying to add SRT(subrip) subtitles to an AVI container.

1) Convert the AVI to a MKV container without re-encoding:

`ffmpeg -fflags +genpts -i input.avi -c:v copy -c:a copy output.mkv`

2) Add the subtitle to the mkv container ("output.mkv" in previous step). E.g:

`ffmpeg -i output.mkv -i input.srt -c copy -c:s srt "output-sub.eng.mkv"`